# Maven how to handle multiple projects and settings.xml in same PC

Tags: maven, build, intellij-idea

I want to have multiple (local) settings.xml files in my PC for my Maven projects, one per project. What is the best way of handling these settings.xml (hopefully somehow through version control)?
I know that each developer (and the CI server) will want to have some different variables in those settings.xml.

I am thinking something like one settings.xml in subversion per project, to provide a skeleton with some empty fields so that everyone can copy and paste the settings.xml file to their local directory where it gets picked up by Maven and also fill in the blank values that are unique per environment/user. Bear in mind, I am not referring to stuff that can be set via profiles, it's more like usernames and passwords and such.

This leaves us with the problem of multiple settings.xml files. IntelliJ as I see has Maven configuration per project so I shouldn't have any trouble setting separate locations for every project. As for the command line, do I really need to type in the path to my settings.xml file every time I run something (via the -s command)?

Comment: I don't see the point to this. The settings file is a file for global configuration like public repositories and proxy settings. If you want a 'per project' configuration. Then use the project configuration: pom.xml

Comment: so let's say that we have (for whatever business reason) separate nexus repositories. You would put those in the parent pom.xml of each project ? Also when it comes down to all kinds of properties that we have in the settings.xml how would you treat those? They are different for every developer (for example username and passwords, some directories etc) and can't really be in the pom.xml as that's the same for everone.

Comment: the repository url where to store or to get your artifact is project specific and should go into your project configuration. The credentials are per user and should therefore go into settings.xml

Comment: "All kinds of properties": give us some examples

Comment: okay, so as you said. Usernames and passwords. I don't want project A's db username and password for example to be visible in my project B. Let's say that I have 100 projects (obviously exaggerating but trying to make a point). If I keep 100 different credentials in my settings.xml it's going to be a mess to maintain. I want those things to be somehow split per project as well, that's why I thought about having different settings.xml files.

Comment: As a sidenote even nexus requires credentials. Right now both the nexus url details and the credentials exist right next to each other in the settings.xml. You would suggest splitting the url to pom.xml and keeping the credentials in settings.xml? Not quite sure, but is that even possible ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48486/discussion-between-absurd-mind-and-sakis-kaliakoudas)

Comment: Sound like you should think about using maven profiles: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles so separate your concerns.

Comment: I'm surprised to not see more traction on this question. I'm a software development contractor working for different clients, each of which typically has their own Nexus servers and requires credentials and other proprietary information in the settings.xml. I imagine that a lot of contractors are facing this exact same problem. Obviously, you don't ever want credentials or proprietary information to get mixed up between clients, so this is a very valid concern. Has anyone come up with a workable solution to this?